# How to create installable for my java application + mysql (jar created from maven build spring boot)

Tags: java, mysql, jar, installation

I want to test my application in other laptop, that doesn't contain any jre or mysql installed on it, so i must manually install those softwares in order to run my jar file on it.
I want to know how installable are made?
I need to install : JRE,MySql Workbench and the sql file to create database , and make the jar file on desktop.
Note: I created the exe with launch4j, so i need just to create the installable file.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest

1. Use flyway or liquibase (or any other) to handle your DDL migrations
2. Dockerize the application (externalize configuration as env variables)
3. Setup a nice docker compose using you app image, mysql and whatever else you need
4. Push to a docker registry and share

Now you have something even more portable than your .exe file.

Regards.

Comment: Thank you for the time taken to answer me, even i didn't understand what you said (as beginner i don't know what is dockerize an application ) but i will search for this solution. Regards